# org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: Access to host class <myClass> is not allowed or does not exists

Tags: javascript, java, karate

I have recently upgraded my application from Java 14 to Java 16 and my Karate version from 0.9.6 to 1.0.1

When the project was on the 0.9.6, I had only one js file with 4 function
Now, I had to split this in 4 different files (1 file per function)

In my background section, I call the different js files :

```
Background:

            Given call read('../../function/randomAlphabetics.js')
            Given call read('../../function/now.js')
            Given call read('../../function/generateClientCredentials.js')
            Given call read('../../function/extractRegexFromHeader.js')
```

All of them are OK except the randomAlphabetics.js :

```
randomAlphabetics = function (length) {
    var randomUtil = Java.type("org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils");
    var str = randomUtil.randomAlphanumeric(length);
    return str;
}
```

When I run my Karate, I have a PolyglotException which I do not how to fix :

`org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: Access to host class org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils is not allowed or does not exist.`

Here is the complete stacktrace of the error :

```
Given call read('../../function/randomAlphabetics.js')
>>>> js failed:
01: function (length) {
02:     var randomUtil = Java.type("org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils");
03:     var str = randomUtil.randomAlphanumeric(length);
04:     return str;
05: }
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: Access to host class org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils is not allowed or does not exist.
 - <js>.randomAlphabetics(Unnamed:2)
```

I have searched on Google and here, but impossible for me to find an issue like mine.. If someone could help, it would be very nice.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: definitely sounds like an issue with your java classpath. in my opinion, this is the best way to solve your problem, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Did anyone find the answer to this problem

Comment: Encountered this error too. Did anyone has an answer to this?